# Angular translate with html and ngHref

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, parameter-passing, angular-translate

I have this key/value in a Json file to use in angular-translate:

```
{"MEETING_LINK": "<br/>Maybe you want to see the <a class=\"pink-link\" ng-href=\"/{{meetingLink}}/{{meetingId}}\">full meeting<a/> first?"}
```

When I invoke the translate in my html like this:

```
 <span 
    ng-bind-html="'GLOBAL.REMOVE_MODAL.MEETING_LINK' | translate:
    { meetingLink: meetingData.buttonLink, meetingId: meetingData.id}">
  </span>
```

It does not work. But if I replace the ng-href in the anchor:`href="/{{meetingData.buttonLink}}/{{meetingData.id}}` It works.
Besides I want to add a ng-click to the anchor element, I guess angular directives in the html do not work.

Can I do some trick to make this happen?

Comment: I doubt angular run the compiler on HTML rendered this way. You could do a custom directive, use an external template file or simply use a proper object and adapted template. Binding a full html string containing actions and some layout tags is probably not a good approach in the first place.

Comment: Certainly your final point is right, I should not introduce angular directives in the html in the Json files. I just want to evict to build a pre-anchor, anchor-text and pos-achor key/values, that is the way I have solved. But maybe it would be a better and elegant way to do this. Actually I'm trying with a directive but I do not get the result I want.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `translate-compile` to your `span` if you're using angular-translate 2.x.